# Why does "might even be in the way" refer to "an obstruction in the way"?

Tags: word-meaning

I see this sentence in my book:

> For many drawings, the Pan & Zoom window isn’t necessary and *might even be in the way*.

I tried to translate this in Googlee Translator and it showed that the meaning of **might even be in the way** is **an obstruction in the way**.

However, when I searched it in Google, I can't find this claims.

May you tell whether Google Translator is right and the reason?

Comment: What does "...was as tinder" mean? Were you translating it from English to your language, or from your language to English?

Comment: @gotube I modified the question. You can inform me if I was still wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what you mean. I think you're using "was as" incorrectly, and I cannot guess your intended meaning.

Comment: The process of translating from language A to language B and translating the result back to language A will often produce bad results. I expect that tinder (a dry material used for lighting fires) is connected to a translated word in the second language. In English the second version makes little sense.

Comment: @gotube How ablout now? I made a change.

Comment: When something is "in the way", it is an obstruction.  So, something that "might even be in the way" is something that "might even be an obstruction".

Comment: In this case, a window you don't need could be _in the way_ because it's taking up part of your screen and possibly hiding part of the image you want.

Comment: @myacorn That may be Google Translator meant to. I never see this meaning before. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It means ["obstructing, blocking, or hindering"](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_the_way).

The pan & zoom window might block some of the window that shows the drawing. It would be in the way, and the user might feel the need to move it *out* of the way.

Answer (score 0):

that the window "might even be in the way" means that it is **possible** that the Pan and Zoom window will block some of the content, making the viewer harder to use.

The phrase "an obstruction in the way" is **not** a good rephrasing of "might even be in the way" and is not good English. An obstruction is by definition something in the way, so "an obstruction in the way" is redundant.

This shows, yet again, that automatic computer translation does not (yet) reliably produce an accurate rendition of the source text, although IMO is it significantly better than it was, say 10 years ago.